# Properly Specifying BRR Replicate Weights in R Survey Package

Tags: r, survey

I am using Lumley's text on the Survey Package; I'm not sure what to indicate for the combined.weights argument.  I looked in the help window on it and it said the argument is true if the BRR weights include the sampling weight (and it also said that it is usually the case).  I am using the National Center for Education Statistics ELS 2002 Dataset.  Any thoughts on the proper combined weights argument?  Also, if the combined.weights argument is true, then scale and rscales have to be specified according to the R help page and I really am not sure how to go about doing that either.  Was not able to find anything very detailed in the help window and other examples I have found vary greatly depending on the dataset involved.  There was another question posted on specifying BRR weights on this site; the person answering showed specifying the BRR weights with the combined.weights argument=TRUE, but then did not specify scale and rscales.  Any guidance is greatly appreciated; I really want my analyses to be accurate, so these specifications about the dataset are critical.
Thank you!

Comment: pdf page 53 of the docs says you can use TSL to match their published standard errors in appendix K, i think once you do that, you're OK.  http://nces.ed.gov/pubs2004/2004405.pdf#page=53

Comment: Thank you and could you please define TSL, as I am afraid I am not familiar with the term.

Comment: hi, taylor series linearization.  creating your design with `svydesign` is generally tsl, whereas creating your design with `svrepdesign` is a replication method

Comment: Thanks, I definitely know Taylor Series Linearization, I guess it was too late for me to figure out the acronym!  The entire reason I have had to delve into BRR is I do not have access to the restricted use data variable that is required to the TSL.  I found a section in the the 3 wave manual for the dataset that talks about the creation of the BRR weights and it seems that the sampling weight is "included" in the BRR weights on pg. 88 of: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5fHCR5TGRjad2dLc3RrUFYtU1E/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Do you agree from that section on p. 88 that the sample weights are "included" in the BRR weights?  If that is true, then all I have to figure out is how to specify the scale and rscales agruments. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to obtain this answer through the U. of Michigan Survey Methodology Program:
combined.weights=TRUE is the default and is probably the right setting for this dataset. If the weights in a replicate sum to something that looks like the pop total of students (or whatever the units are), then combined.weights=TRUE is correct.

According to Lumley's book, sec, 2.3.1 (link below), R survey will figure out what scale and rscale for BRR and Fay. For fay she does have to specify rho, the Fay factor.

https://books.google.com/books?id=L96ludyhFBsC&pg=PP35&lpg=PP35&dq=combined.weights+in+R+survey&source=bl&ots=ic-u-jnCv1&sig=g9RfrFezc_42Qr-__U3d5QTMER4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJ-o6wyaDMAhUKdT4KHUmgBK4Q6AEIWjAJ#v=onepage&q=combined.weights%20in%20R%20survey&f=false